# Unable to log in. xsession-errors file looks like it could be useful if I understood

Tags: linux-mint, login, path

I am unable to log in to my account, having recently installed Linux Mint. I had this problem with Ubuntu 13.10, and no amount of re-installations seemed to fix it. However, Mint gives me a *very* useful window alerting me that my session lasted less than 10 seconds, and displays the contents of my ~/.xsession-errors file, before returning me to the login screen. I have been able to access the terminal to execute commands thus far, and I have verified that my $PATH variable is:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/user/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

The contents of my .xsession-errors is:

```
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 1: /etc/profile: id: not found
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 12: [: Illegal number: 
/etc/mdm/Xsession: Executing default failed, will try to run x-terminal-emulator
/etc/mdm/Xsession: 205: exec: x-terminal-emulator: not found
```

EDIT: After being advised to select "Cinnamon" from the login option screen, I tried it and it didn't work. The new .xsession-errors file can be found at: http://pastebin.com/36F4daQU

It looks like useful information, but, being new to Linux, I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: Please post your `/etc/mdm/Xsession` and `/etc/profile` files. Is this a fresh install or are you installing somewhere that had another Linux before (and have not formatted)?

Comment: /etc/profile: http://pastebin.com/qw80Qjyw
/etc/mdm/xsession: http://pastebin.com/23MadAPF

During installation, the boot and root partitions were formatted. I've left the home partition intact so as to keep my personal files.

Comment: OK, it is looking for a Desktop Environment you don't have installed, which one were you using before (Gnome? Cinnamon? KDE? Unity? xfce?) and which one do you want to use now?

Comment: I was using Ubuntu, which I think uses Unity, but now on Mint I'm using (or trying to, rather) use Cinnamon.

Comment: OK, have you selected Cinnamon in the login screen? It is trying to launch Unity because that is the default session saved in your `$HOME`.

Comment: I haven't, but I'll try it now and see.

Comment: Tried it, but the issue persists. The xsession-errors file has changed, though: http://pastebin.com/36F4daQU

Comment: See my updated answer but it is also strange that your system apparently has no `id` command, did the install finish successfuly?

Comment: The install completed with no errors. I tried moving all the files you suggested in your answer, and I'll try logging in again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Mint is trying to load your default session which is apparently stored in one the files read by `/etc/mdm/Xsession`, most probably `~/.xsessionrc` if you have it.

In any case, the simplest solution would be to choose Cinnamon from the login menu options and save that as your default.

If that doesn't work, try moving the relevant files (not sure which one is causing the issue here):

```
mkdir old_dotfiles
mv ~/.x* ~/.X* old_dotfiles
```

Then try to log in again. If that works, you can copy the files back one by one to see which one was breaking but unless you know you have modified them, just leave them.

As a last resort, you can simply move all your old dotfiles to a new directory and try logging in again. Since the issue is a setting kept from your previous installation, this should fix it:

```
mkdir olddotfiles; 
mv ~/.[A-Za-z0-9]* olddotfiles
```

All your old config files are now in `$HOME/olddotfiles` and you can move them back one by one if you want to restore them. Just make sure you don't move the problematic one.

Comment: I just tried that and I still couldn't log in. The xsession-errors file changed and can be found at: http://pastebin.com/36F4daQU

Comment: @user256491 is cinnamon actually installed? See jpdated answer for a possible workaround if it is.

Comment: How do I check if cinnamon is actually installed? I mean it should be, but that's a good idea.

Comment: @user256491 if you have some shell available `dpkg -l cinnamon | grep ii`

Comment: Tried moving files all about and nothing worked. Tried the command suggested by Braiam. Not sure if the formatting is important so I tried a screenshot instead: http://i.imgur.com/dn82nfL.png

Comment: @user256491 yes it's installed but what are you running that from? That is a working terminal running in an X environment. How did you log in?

Comment: Using the bootable USB created from the Linux Mint .iso file. I access the actual files on my hard drive by opening them in Nemo as root then Right-Click > open in Terminal.

Comment: In that case, the command output you pasted is irrelevant, that was querying the live CD system. I thought you said you could log in at a text console. Try hitting Ctrl+Alt+F1 from the login screen (of the installed system, not the CD) and logging in there. _Then_ run the `dpkg` command. Also, are you sure you moved the right files? Not their copies in the live CD?

Comment: I checked from the login screen using Ctrl+Alt+F1 and confirmed that the files had indeed been moved. I'll try running the `dpkg` command again.

Comment: Tried it. No dice. the output is as follows: `ii cinnamon   2.0.14+petra        amd64 Cinnamon desktop`

Comment: @user256491 OK, lets just make sure it works, try logging in as another user. First, create a new user (from the Ctrl+Alt+F1 command line) with `sudo adduser foo`, follow the prompts, switch back to the GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7 (or F8, depends) and try logging in as `foo`.

Comment: Created user Foo, but I had to reboot in order for the GUI to give me the option to login as Foo. Upon reboot, I am now logged in as Foo with no errors. So I guess that's a good thing.

Comment: @user256491 yes. So, everything is OK, there must be some other file in your $HOME that is screwing things up. Try this command and let me know the results: `grep grep -i unity /home/youroldusername/.* 2>/dev/null`

Comment: The output is different when I do it from the terminal as my old user and when I do it as foo. As foo, it only prints

`/home/sorou/.bashrc:    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
/home/sorou/.bashrc:    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
/home/sorou/.bashrc:    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'`

But as the old user, it prints all of that, along with the following: 

`/home/sorou/.bash_history:spci | grep -i pci || lspci
/home/sorou/.bash_history:/sbin/lspci | grep audio
/home/sorou/.bash_history:dpkg -l cinnamon | grep ii
Binary file /home/sorou/.steampath matches`

Comment: @user256491 sorry, that was supposed to be `grep -i unity /home/youroldusername/.*`, not `grep grep`. Never mind, I got what I needed. OK, try this instead `find /home/oldusername/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '.*'  -exec grep -liR unity {} 2>/dev/null \;`. The idea is to find which file is giving you the problem.

Comment: the second command is taking quite a while to execute. Is there something specific I should have done that I might not have? 4 minutes in and it's still running.

Comment: @user256491 that is probably looking through the `.cache` folder which is not that relevant. You could also just remove all possible culprits: `mkdir olddotfiles; mv /home/olduser/.[A-Za-z0-9]* olddotfiles`. That will move all your settings files from your old account to the new directory `olddotfiles` that you just created but will not touch your data. That should solve your issue. Assuming it does and assuming you want to keep any of those settings you can then start copying them back again.

Comment: It worked. I can now log in to my old username through the GUI and all of my old files appear to be intact. I should point out that when running the `mv` command it returned the error `cannot move '/home/sorou/.gvfs' to 'olddotfiles/.gvfs':Permission denied.` But otherwise everything seems to be working perfectly. Thanks a million. You have no idea how much I appreciate it. Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: @user256491 no problem, that's what the site is for. I'll update my answer with the solution, please remember to accept it (that's how thanks are given on the SE sites).