# Mint Display Manager says "g_key_file_free: assertion 'key_file ! NULL failed" after I re-built glib

Tags: linux-mint, glib

I'm on Linux Mint 17.
I can't open ma session. An error message appear with:

```
initctl: Unable to connect to upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
mdm[1448]: GLib-CRITICAL: g_key_file_free: assertion 'key_file ! NULL failed
```

And as it happens, I download source file of glib today using aptitude.

```
aptitude download libglib2.0-dev //Don't remember exactly the command I type
```

I needed to overwrite the existing glib by the one I downloaded for a specific project. So I install using:

```
 - ./configure
 - ./make
 - ./make install
```

So now the one I download overwrite the one which was install by default.
However I can't  get into my session anymore. So I think it's a problem about compatibility or something else...

So does anyone can explain me how can I overwrite the glib I install by the default one ? Or simply explain me how can I get into my session.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that cinnamon on your system got hosed somehow. Same thing happened to me. Follow the instructions from this post to fix it:

[xsession-errors on linux mint 17.2. No solutions found from similar questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247685/xsession-errors-on-linux-mint-17-2-no-solutions-found-from-similar-questions)

tl;dr

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
sudo reboot
```